# Sending email to SMTP server from Google Cloud VM, NGinx, Docker Container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a google cloud compute instance that is hosting docker containers, one of which is nginx with a reverse proxy, connecting to my server.

My server is trying to send notification emails via an external smtp server. In this case a test gmail account before switching to the company smtp server.

I have tried the following:

- Opening (Exposing) up port 587 on the different docker containers.
- Adding Postfix with a loopback-only

From what I have read it seems that google have opened the 587 port for outgoing calls by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had to open the correct ports on the docker containers.
Port 587 are open on google cloud vm's.